# Need commands to grep Unknown number of lines before after locating the search String in the files

Tags: grep

I have a file named `basefile.txt` with huge number of lines. The records in the file are logically grouped based on their sets.

E.g.:

```
"GRP_START","LINE1"........
"A"
"B--BOOM"
"C"
"GRP_START","LINE1"........
"A"
"B--DOOM"
"C"
"D"
"E"
"F"
"G"
"GRP_START","LINE1"........
"E"
"F"
"G"
"C--MOOM"
"GRP_START","LINE1"........
```

What I want to do is, I have those these search strings in a separate file named `keywords.txt` which contains below data:

```
BOOM
DOOM
MOOM
```

I need a command which will read the text one by one from `keywords.txt` file and search that text in the `basefile.txt` and write certain records into a `finalfile.txt`

Those certain records are:
 I need the Sets where the search text is falling.

E.g: In the above files.

the command should search for BOOM and return the below lines

```
"GRP_START","LINE1"........
"A"
"B--BOOM"
"C"
```

the command should search for DOOM and return the below lines

```
"GRP_START","LINE1"........
"A"
"B--DOOM"
"C"
"D"
"E"
"F"
"G"
```

So, GRP_START is the start of a set and till the next GRP_START I want the records to be written to the `finalfile.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

The following `awk` script will read through the data file and temporarily store each record in the `lines` variable. If the keyword in the variable `word` is found in the record, the `do_output` variable is set to 1 (true). When the keyword has been found and we either reach the next record or the end of the file, the keyword record is outputted.

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/^"GRP_START"/ {
    if (do_output) {
        exit;
    }
    lines = $0;
    next;
}

$0 ~ word {
    do_output = 1;
}

{
    lines = sprintf("%s\n%s", lines, $0);
}

END {
    if (do_output) {
        print lines;
    }
}
```

Testing it:

```
$ awk -v word="MOOM" -f script.awk basefile.txt
"GRP_START","LINE1"........
"E"
"F"
"G"
"C--MOOM"
```

Then it's just a matter of looping over the wanted keywords:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

while read -r word; do
  awk -v word="$word" -f script.awk basefile.txt
done <keywords.txt >finalfile.txt
```

Suggestion for future improvement: Read the keywords into an array first, then parse the `basefile.txt` data file only once.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{re=re (re?"|":"")$0;next} /^"GRP_START"/{if (rec~re)print rec; rec=$0;next} {rec=rec"\n"$0} END{if (rec~re)print rec}' keywords.txt basefile.txt
```

Example:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{re=re (re?"|":"")$0;next} /^"GRP_START"/{if (rec~re)print rec; rec=$0;next} {rec=rec"\n"$0} END{if (rec~re)print rec}' keywords.txt basefile.txt 
"GRP_START","LINE1"........
"A"
"B--BOOM"
"C"
"GRP_START","LINE1"........
"A"
"B--DOOM"
"C"
"D"
"E"
"F"
"G"
"GRP_START","LINE1"........
"E"
"F"
"G"
"C--MOOM"
```

#### How it works

- `FNR==NR{re=re (re?"|":"")$0;next}`

  While reading the first file, `keywords.txt`, we construct a regular expression to match any of the words.  For the sample data, for example, this creates the variable `re` with the value `BOOM|DOOM|MOOM`.
- `/^"GRP_START"/{if (rec~re)print rec; rec=$0;next}`

  Every time we reach the start of a new record, we check to see if the last record, stored in `rec` matches the regular expressions stored in `re`.  If it does, we print it.  Next, `rec` is reset to the current line and we skip the rest of the commands and jump to the `next` line.
- `rec=rec"\n"$0`

  For all other lines, we append them to `rec`.
- `END{if (rec~re)print rec}`

  After we finish reading the file, we check to see if the final record matches the regex `re` and, if so, we print it.